# How to get time in PHP with nanosecond precision?

Tags: php, datetime, nanotime

Is this even possible in PHP?

If not, what is the highest precision available?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need nanosecond precision in PHP?

Comment: I'm doing something involving time synchronisation, where a program asks the remote server for it's time. Java can give the time in nanoseconds, so I thought it would be cool if I could get PHP to do that too rather than wasting the extra precision.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function is what you're looking for.

PHP does not supply a function that has higher precision than microseconds.

You can use the [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function to get the value straight from the machine if you are running Linux:

```
$nanotime = system('date +%s%N');
```

**`%s`** is the amount of seconds, appended by **`%N`**, which is the amount of nanoseconds.

Comment: I'm running linux, but for some reason that returns 0. Does it not work on lighttpd?

Comment: I just noticed and fixed that after googling date :P But something strange is happening, it just returns seemingly random 9 digit numbers like 519716810. It does the same when I run the command in SSH, so I don't think it's a data type issue with PHP.

Comment: If I run the command a few times in a for loop, the numbers increase from 0........ to 9........, and then back again. So it does seem like the first half of the number is missing.

Comment: Got it, I think it should be date +%s%N, because %N doesn't bother showing the seconds part.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: A system call like `system` need to spawn a shell and return output to PHP. Wouldn't that take a lot more than a nanosecond? If so, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of find time to nanosecond precision? Please advice.

Comment: system() is writing to output, exec('date +%s%N') is more correct

Comment: Think twice, do you really need nanoseconds, becuase there's performance drop:
exec('date +%s%N'): 3.1263501644135 seconds;
round(microtime(true) * 1000): 0.0062530040740967 seconds;
Tested on 1000 cycles with calling this functions.

Comment: Of interest, PHP does implement `time_nanosleep()` which is the only function I know that exposes nanoseconds.

Comment: system('date +%s%N') makes me like a type of echo, so in a ajax result apear.

Answer (score 18):

Now with this extension it's nanosecond timing is possible http://pecl.php.net/hrtime . Yet it is a stopwatch class implemented to suite the highest possible resolution on different platforms.

As of PHP 7.3 there's also a crossplatform `hrtime()` function in the core http://php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer since `hrtime()`'s doc says "Returns an array of integers in the form [seconds, nanoseconds]."

Answer (score 14):

[microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) is the highest precision using PHP's vocabulary. You can also make a system call by using Unix `date` and specify `%N` format if you need nanosecond accuracy. Unix `ntp_gettime()` has even higher resolution and returns jitter/wander/stability/shift/calibration data.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping there would be something higher than that =[